# Create if statement to iterate over a list of names and create name if not in list?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, azure-devops, devops

I am working with an Azure shared image gallery and trying to write a bash `if` statement to iterate through the list of image definition names and `if` that image definition name is not there, create it `elif`, etc...

I have a variable set as:

```
defs=$(az sig image-definition list --resource-group $MyRG --gallery-name $mySIG --query [*].name) \
echo "$defs"
```

What I'm attempting to do is create an if statement that will iterate through this list of image definition names in my Azure compute gallery, and create a specified name if it does not exist.
My original assumption was something like `if [$defs != x` but not sure how to go about setting x, as it would be a user input for someone wanting to create a new definition.

Sorry if my question is unclear.
If there's more info I can provide please let me know.

The problem I'm facing is that I understand bash somewhat but not in conjunction with how exactly I am attempting to apply it to my Azure image definitions issue.

Comment: please update the question with the complete output from `typeset -p defs` so we can see the exact contents of the variable; also consider updating the question to show the complete/actual code you've attempted (along with a sample value of `x`), the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output; making sure all outputs correspond to the sample data in `defs`

Comment: To iterate over a collection of data, you need a list, which in bash means: An indexed array. I suggest that you make `defs` an array, and then use a loop over the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `read` to ask a user for input.

```bash
$ read -p "please enter a definition: " x
please enter a definition: def4
$ echo $x
def4
```

Then, assuming $defs is a space separated list of definitions, could do something like this:

```bash
# list of defs..
defs="def1 def2 def3"

# ask user to enter a definition
read -p "please enter a definition: " x

# set this to false until def is found
def_exists=false

# iterate over list of defs and see if user value is found
for i in ${defs}; do
  echo $i
  if [[ ${i} == "${x}" ]]; then
    echo "found it"
    def_exists=true
  fi
done

# if user def exists, good
if $def_exists; then
  echo "definition exists already.. nothing to do"

# otherwise...
else
  # do something
  echo "$x not found.. do stuff.."
fi
```

Example where def is in existing list:

```bash
please enter a definition: def1
def1
found it
def2
def3
definition exists already.. nothing to do
```

Example where def is not in existing list:

```bash
please enter a definition: def4
def1
def2
def3
def4 not found.. do stuff..
```

This is what my `defs` variable holds, and what the commenter above was asking you to provide so we can see what type of data is being referenced.

```bash
$ typeset -p defs
declare -- defs="def1 def2 def3"
```

If the data/ definitions have spaces, etc.. could use arrays or we can look at other options. If you post some examples of the definitions, like are they a single word? multiple words with spaces in them, etc. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Global Parameters --query and --output to query the list from the output of az sig image-version list in  Azure CLI. Please refer to :[az sig image-definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sig/image-definition?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sig-image-definition-list)

For example:

```
defs=$(az sig image-definition list --resource-group Wicresoft-Support --gallery-name douGallery --query [*].name --output tsv)
```

And then use  `typeset -p defs` to see the exact contents of the variable. It’s a string structure from the below picture.

[image: tyeset]

For example, here is bash script with Azure CLI

```
# convert to array
defs_array=($defs)
#declare -p defs_array
# the length of array
length=${#defs_array[@]}
read -p "please enter a name: " x
for i in ${defs_array[@]}
do
if [[ ${i} == $x ]]; then
    echo "found"
    break
else
   if [[ ${i} == ${defs_array[-1]} ]];then
      echo "not found"
   fi 
fi
done
```

Comment: How the issue is going? If it helps, just a remind of accept an answer.  If not, i‘ll stay focused on your issue.